# Каким редактором можно открыть и отредактировать .dat, чтобы значения были визуально понятными?

Tags: ios, файлы

Привет всем! Есть файл с расширением .dat, находится в файлах одной игры на ios (какая игра, догадается тот, кто знает правильный ответ). В общем, вопрос такой: каким редактором можно открыть и отредактировать, чтобы значения были визуально понятными?

Заранее благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Никто вам не ответит, расширение dat ни о чем не говорит. Фактически так называют любые файлики с данными, внутри может быть, что угодно, не определено даже в бинарном ли виде или в текстовом оно там будет, не говоря уж про структуру, могут быть даже просто значения одно за другим записаны без уточнения, что есть что, - все полностью на усмотрение программы, которая файл создала.

Я бы на вашем месте сначала попытался открыть текстовым редактором, а потом каким-нибудь Hex-редактором и понять, что к чему.

Comment: я пытался открыть с notepad++ кракозябры а какой Hex редактор посоветуете?

Comment: значит бинарный формат.

Я почти не пользуюсь хексом, когда надо мне хватает iHex из стора

Answer (score 0):

После 5 секунд гугла:

> Общий формат для хранения данных различными приложениями. Как правило, файл DAT можно открыть только программой, которая создала этот файл. Данные могут храниться как в текстовом, так и в двоичном виде. Текстовые файлы DAT можно просмотреть в любом текстовом редакторе.
>
> Примеры программ, которые создают и используют файлы DAT: Microsoft Visual Studio, Corel WordPerfect, Nero ShowTime, Nullsoft Winamp, SoftVelocity Clarion, Ontrack EasyRecovery, Runtime GetDataBack, программное обеспечение MapInfo.

Comment: Это я тоже гуглил, а как узнать, на чем писали игру?

Comment: Попробуйте скопировать и погуглить первые несколько шеснадцатиричных первых чисел (около 8) - они могут быть сигнатурой файла, но опять-таки - нету никаких правил, что захотела записать программа, то и будет внутри, могут с первого же бита идти просто данные.

Comment: > это я тоже гуглил а как узнать на чем писали программу игру?

Так как это iOS, то очевидно, что это скорее всего Objective C (менее вероятно - Swift/C/C++).

Comment: ТС просто не правильно сформулировал, ему нужно не на чем писали прогу (игру), а на чем создали его бинарный datник.